# Vanishing first Chern class implies existence of flat connection

Tags: differential-geometry, characteristic-classes

**Edit**: In the exercise I tried to solve it wasn't stated explicitly that we were dealing with line bundles (though the usage of the symbol $L$ for the vector bundle was a strong suggestion that this was the case), hence why my ponderings in the question post are about vector bundles of arbitrary rank.

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $E$ a complex rank $r$ vector bundle on $M$. My definition of the first Chern class $c_1(E)$ of $E$ is
$$
c_1(E)=\left[\text{tr}\left(\frac{i}{2\pi}F^\nabla\right)\right] \in H_{\text{dR}}^2(M)
$$
where $F^\nabla$ is the curvature tensor corresponding to any connection $\nabla$ on $E$.

If $E$ admits a flat connection $\nabla$, then $F^\nabla=0$, and hence $c_1(E)=0$. I want to prove that the converse is true too: if $c_1(E)=0$, then $E$ admits a flat connection.

I know the identity $c_1(E)=c_1(\Lambda^r E)$. Since $\Lambda^r E$ is a line bundle, $c_1(\Lambda^r E)$ is simply the cohomology class of the curvature $F^{\nabla^{\Lambda^r E}}$, where $\nabla^E$ is some connection on $E$ and $\nabla^{\Lambda^r E}$ is the induced connection on $\Lambda^r E$. So $c_1(\Lambda^r E)=0$ means that $F^{\nabla^{\Lambda^r E}}$ is an exact $2$-form.

Maybe I should first show the case that if a complex line bundle $L$ has vanishing first Chern class, then $L$ admits a flat connection, and maybe I can then show that a flat connection on $\Lambda^r E$ is induced by a flat connection on $E$?

Any hints are welcome.

Context: all I know about characteristic classes is what's treated in chapter 5 of Tu's Differential Geometry book, which I've learned is not the modern way of doing things. And see below the exercise that I'm trying to solve.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a reference for this claim? By the way, it is not true in this generality in the holomorphic setting. This is essentially a consequence of the Hitchin-Kobayashi correspondence, see for example https://mathoverflow.net/q/49995

Comment: It's an exercise in my Differential Geometry course notes, so all I have is a screenshot of said exercise, which I've included in the post now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $L$ admits a flat connection then obviously $c_1(L)=0$. Conversely, suppose $c_1(L)=0$. Pick a connection $\nabla$ on $L$. Then, by definition, $F_\nabla=d\eta$ for some $1$-form $\eta\in\Omega^1(X)$. As you know from the course, the space of connections is an affine space, and we can define the connection $\nabla'=\nabla-\eta$. Say that the local connection $1$-forms are $A$ and $A'$ respectively. Then the local curvature $2$-form is $$F_{\nabla'}=dA'=d(A-\eta)=dA-d\eta=F_{\nabla}-d\eta=0$$
Hence $\nabla'$ is a flat connection on $L$.

Comment: Right, because we have a line bundle, the difference $\nabla-\nabla'$ between two connection lies in $\Omega^1(M)\otimes\Gamma(\text{End}(L))\cong\Omega^1(M)$. For some reason I hadn't realised that it also goes the other way around: given $\eta\in\Omega^1(M)$ and a connection $\nabla$, then $\nabla-\eta$ also defines a connection. This is good to be aware of. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I wonder how you guarantee $\eta$ is not $\nabla$?

Comment: It is not possible for $\eta$ to be $\nabla$, one is a $1$-form, the other is a connection. Those are different things. The question would lead me to suspect that you've misunderstood something about the relation between $1$-forms and connections. If so, do tell.